# What is the rationale behind the ability to integrate both sides of a separable differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From [Paul's Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx):
[image: separable differential equation]
What is the rationale for the last line here?  Why is it possible to do this integration? (I assume the left side is being integrated with respect to y and the left side with respect to x.)

Comment: Well you don't need to assume as it is clear from the dy and dx

Comment: in short, it is the chain rule. But, really you're asking for a proof of u-substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to calculate with dy and dx as if they were numbers, just leave it likes this:
$N(y(x))y'(x) = M(x)$. Then integrate both sides with respect to $x$.

You get $\int N(y(x))y'(x) dx = \int M(x)dx$. Then substitute $y(x) = u$ on the left side and receive

$\int N(u) du = \int M(x) dx$.

Of course you can rename $u$ to $y$ again. I just used $u$ here to make the substitution better visable.